# How to create an S4 class A that will have a list of S4 classes B as its attribute?

Tags: r, r-s4

I am quite new to R so my question might have an obvious answer.

I am trying to create something like this

```
A {
  list: B []
}
```

Where both A and B are S4 classes. How to achieve that?

EDIT

I actually do not care at this point whether `list` attribute is an array or an actual list. For my use case it is fairly irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define S4 classes with `setClass`, and within this you use `representation` to declare members and their types.

In this case, class `A` needs only contain a member of type `list` to house the collection of objects of S4 class `B`.

```r
setClass("A", representation(List = "list"))
setClass("B", representation(value = "numeric"))
```

You declare new S4 objects with the function `new`, in which you specify the class name first and their members as named parameters:

```r
my_object <- new("A", List = list(new("B", value = 1), new("B", value = 2)))
my_object
#> An object of class "A"
#> Slot "List":
#> [[1]]
#> An object of class "B"
#> Slot "value":
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> An object of class "B"
#> Slot "value":
#> [1] 2
```

We can get the `List` member using the `@` operator:

```
my_object@List
#> [[1]]
#> An object of class "B"
#> Slot "value":
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> An object of class "B"
#> Slot "value":
#> [1] 2
```

From which we can access the list members, and their S4 slots directly:

```r
my_object@List[[1]]
#> An object of class "B"
#> Slot "value":
#> [1] 1

my_object@List[[1]]@value
#> [1] 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>